# Relation symmetric confusion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

So Symmetric = (a,b), (b,a)

```
Set = {<1, 1>, <1, 2>, <1, 4>, <2, 1>, <2, 2>, <3, 3>, <4,1 >, <4, 4>}
```

I understand <1,2> and <2,1> is symmetric, but are <2,2>, <3,3> and <4,4> necessary here to form a symmetric set?

Could someone please specify why is this set a symmetric?

Answer (score 1):

> The pairs you list in your set $R$ are not symmetric; it is the relation $R$ itself that is symmetric. Symmetry is a property of a relation and not a property of the elements that are related.

To be a symmetric relation, we must have that for all $x, y$ in the set on which the relation is defined, that **if** it's the case that $\langle x, y\rangle \in R$, then so must be $\langle y, x\rangle \in R$. If some pair $\langle a, b\rangle \notin R$, then we can't have $\langle b, a\rangle \in R$.

> Another way to think of this is that a relation $R$ **IS** Symmetric...**unless** there exists a pair $\langle x, y\rangle \in R$, but $\langle y, x\rangle \notin R$.

In the case of $\langle x, x\rangle \in R$, it is trivially true that by symmetry, $\langle x, x\rangle \in R$. But it is *not* necessary that the pairs of the form $\langle x, x\rangle$ are in the relation $R$ to be symmetric. It would be symmetric without pairs of that form.

Answer (score 0):

You should write the definition more carefully.  Symmetric means $(a,b) \in R \implies (b,a) \in R$  Note that this says the empty relation is symmetric.  You can have $(2,2)$ (and the others) in or out without changing the fact that the relation is symmetric.  The way to destroy symmetry would be to remove $(1,2)$ without removing $(2,1)$ or to add $(2,3)$ without adding $(3,2)$

Answer (score 0):

Symmetry means that
$$
(a,b)\in R\Rightarrow (b,a) \in R
$$
Here, <2,2>, <3,3>, and <4,4> are not required to be in the set. If they were, then the set would be reflexive, which is defined as
$$
R\subseteq A\times A\\
\forall a\in A \Rightarrow (a,a) \in R
$$